# Rendering problems with xml drawable

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

In android studio if I set a .xml drawable as a backgrouns I get Rendering Problems and when run app - see no background.

For example I can't set this xml as a background for layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:src="@drawable/bad" />
```

If I add, for example,

```
android:tileMode="repeat"
```

result is the same. Also I see red exclamation mark near my background:

[image]

Here is stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.graphics.Bitmap_Delegate.createBitmap(Bitmap_Delegate.java:614)
at android.graphics.Bitmap_Delegate.createBitmap(Bitmap_Delegate.java:122)
at android.graphics.Bitmap_Delegate.createBitmap(Bitmap_Delegate.java:104)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getDrawable(ResourceHelper.java:249)
at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getDrawable(BridgeTypedArray.java:674)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3730)
at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:491)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:200)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:196)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:192)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor302.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:82)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:128)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:400)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:332)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$5.compute(RenderService.java:708)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$5.compute(RenderService.java:697)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:932)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:697)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.render(RenderService.java:816)
at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$6.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:480)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:327)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Simply copy the image to drawable folder instead of doing this

Comment: Of course my image is in drawable folder. But I want to make custom background, for example, with tile mode. I just show this code as an example

Comment: why do you use bitmap then?

Comment: bad.png is a bitmap. app_background.xml is a xml. I want to create background drawable with tile mode.

Comment: go to drawable folder and copy `bad.png` in it instead of creating xml with bitmap tag. Your image will be visible like `ic_launcher`(default image)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fond the solution. It was pretty simple.

I needed to rename `app_background` to `app_background.xml`

Android studio created file "app_background" by default with no ".xml" extention. I thought that Android studio was hiding .xml from me, but when I opened folder in explorer I realised the real name of the file

Answer (score 0):

Please copy the image(Ex. bad.png) in drawable folder.
then create background.xml in drawable folder and paste below code

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:src="@drawable/bad"
        android:tileMode="repeat" />`

then in your layout set background as android:background="@drawable/background"